# Route part of a subnet to a different gateway

Tags: cisco, subnet, gateway, ip-routing, hp-procurve

Data network is 10.220.0.0/20
DG is 10.220.1.19

I am trying to have all traffic in 10.220.8.0 - 10.220.15.255 (10.220.8.0/21) routed to this gateway: 10.220.1.251

I can't seem to accomplish this at the switch level. I know I can manually assign devices in this range the new gateway or update the DHCP scope to reflect that but I'm trying to accomplish this with routing if possible.

Comment: You'll need to use policy routing for this. Details of how to do this (or if it's even possible) are dependent on your routing equipment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @EEAA I will try it out. Running HP ProCurve Switches latest generation.

Comment: What model switches? Are they L3 or L2 switches? The policy routing needs to happen wherever these systems gateway is.

Comment: 1 HP 5412r zl2 switch, 6 HP 2920 (J97229A) switches, all layer 3 switches, but only the MDF switch does all the IP routing (HP 5412r zl2 switch), so the policy would go on the 5412r zl2 switch right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: most of the documentation I find is on Cisco. I created the access list "51" to permit 10.220.8.0 0.0.7.255 but I'm struggling to route all source traffic from access-list "51" to the second gateway 10.220.1.251